# SimpleSocketServer

Tags: java, sockets, daemon, logback

I am using logback's SimpleSocketServer class as a daemon to log events. If one process is logging to the the daemon(SimpleSocketServer) all is fine, however if two processes begin to log to the daemon at the same time then logging events are either skipped or never received. Has anyone ever dealt with logback and a similar problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be a logback bug? If you think it is, please enter a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Their SocketNode class makes the common mistake of doing I/O or DNS operations in its constructor, which holds up the accept loop that creates it. All that should be deferred to its run() method.